# How to install aptitude without an internet connection?

Tags: installation, aptitude

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.04 and there no internet connection.

Firstly I've tried `sudo apt-get install aptitude`, but it says that there's no installation for this.

Then I downloaded on USB memory `apt_0.8.3ubuntu6_amd64.deb` package (as I understood that this package has aptitude installation) and installed it. Then I tried `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and again no success.

How to install aptitude without internet connection?

Comment: If you installed `aptitude` from `deb` file, why do you also want to install it from repositories?

Comment: Because I don't know meaning of apt-get command, please just say what to do. Thanks

Comment: You should ask yourself why do you need `aptitude`. If you really need it and you really installed it from deb, just run it.

Comment: I need aptitude to configure internet connection(by manual) and of course I've tried to just run it.

Comment: @megas `aptitude` has nothing to do with configuring an internet connection.  It is just another package installer, like `apt-get`.  It is its own package, not part of the apt package, which is why installing the apt package did not help.  You want `aptitude_0.6.3-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb`

Comment: It's for manual, by this manual i suppose to setup vpn connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install **aptitude** without internet you first need to have it with all of its dependencies.

1. Go to: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/aptitude to grab aptitude and all of its dependencies.
2. Put all the deb packages inside a folder and when on the PC you want to install aptitude go to the folder in the terminal and do `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

It will install aptitude with all of the dependencies in that folder.

NOTE - I am also one of those that enjoys Aptitude over apt-get, not only because you do everything from one single command but when you do a show, search or install it is more human friendly than the other.

Answer (score 1):

You install .deb package using `dpkg`, see here for example: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-how-do-i-install-deb-packages/

Also, read this article for installing packages from a CD, without an internet connection:
https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/add-applications/C/offline.html